# How to replace bean in BeanFactory with own mock in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

To implement the factory in a project, I use a Spring's `BeanFactory`. Therefore, the extraction of the required `provider` is as follows:

```
@Override
    public T getInstance(String key) {
        // ...
        return beanFactory.getBean(registry.get(key));
}
```

Thus, I can extract providers as follows:

```
amazingProviderFactory.getInstance("some key");
```

It works fine. But for tests, it is necessary to extract a provider from the `BeanFactory` and replace it with own mocked-implementation.

The following method can solve the problem, but this is only an example found on the Internet, and it's not quite clear how to implement it correctly:

```
Mockito.when(SpringContext.getBean("some key")).thenReturn(mockedProvider);
```

What are the right ways to accomplish the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `@MockBean` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking about :

> But for tests, it is necessary to extract a provider from the
>   BeanFactory and replace it with own mocked-implementation.

Why would you do it ?
Rather you would write a separate unit test for each of the provider and mock any IO operation as required.
You could also have a separate minimal test for your own implemented BeanFactory which test out getInstance method.

Still if you want to do this then something like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProviderTest {

    @MockBean
    private ProviderA providerA;

    @MockBean
    private ProviderB providerB;
}
```

Now `amazingProviderFactory.getInstance("some key");` should return mocked bean as declard above.

Hope this helps.